# Password validation with sequential numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check if has a 2 numbers sequence, if has comes back true, if not false.

example:

```
113489 //false on 11
123456 // true
189033 // false on 33
```

Can be with regex or without regex.

Comment: Saying this is "password validation" frightens me. Are you saying that your requirements for choosing a valid password requires that there are not two identical numbers in a row? Does that imply your passwords must be only numbers? (a _horrible_ idea) — writing your own password management and validation is perilous and usually creates security holes, because it is _hard to get right_; it is better to use an existing package that has been well-tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without regex by just looping over it

```js
var str = "189033";

function check(str) {

  var arr = str.split("");
  var last = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var digit = arr[i]
    if (digit == last) {
      return false;
    }
    last = digit;
  }
  return true;
}
console.log(check(str))
console.log(check("123456"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Test for all numbers, and use a negative lookahead for two consecutive identical numbers:

```js
[
  '113489', //false on 11
  '123456', // true
  '189033' // false on 33
].forEach(str => {
  let isValid = /^(?!.*([0-9])\1)[0-9]+$/.test(str);
  console.log(str + ' => ' + isValid)
});
```

Result:

```
113489 => false
123456 => true
189033 => false
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` -- anchor at start of string
- `(?!.*([0-9])\1)` -- negative lookahead for a single digit `[0-9]`, followed by the same digit (`\1` back references the first capture group)
- `[0-9]+` -- expect just numbers
- `$` -- anchor at end of string